# Scrollspy with jQuery and scrollTo plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a ScrollSpy on a website that i'm developing.

Here's the link of the tutorial i'm following

[Tutorial](http://callmenick.com/2013/04/22/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation/)

And here the demo:

[Demo](http://callmenick.com/lab-demos/7-single-page-smooth-scroll/)

I'm trying to adapt their script to my needs, but i keep getting a error on javascript, the console says that "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Here's my Javascript

```
*/$(document).ready(function(){


$(".menu li a").click(function(evn){
    evn.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);
});

/**
 * This part handles the highlighting functionality.
 * We use the scroll functionality again, some array creation and
 * manipulation, class adding and class removing, and conditional testing
 */
var aChildren = $(".menu li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {
    var aChild = aChildren[i];
    var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
    aArray.push(ahref);
} // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
    var docHeight = $(document).height();

    for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
        var theID = aArray[i];
        if (theID.length) {
            var divPos = $(theID).offset().top;
            var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
            if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().addClass("active");
            } else {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().removeClass("active");
            }
        }
    }

    if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
        if (!$(".menu li:last-child a").hasClass("active")) {
            var navActiveCurrent = $(".active").attr("href");
            $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("active");
            $(".menu li:last-child a").addClass("active");
        }
    }
}); });
```

and here's the web site i'm developing

[Web-Site](http://www.zehenrique.net.br/)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are using href as a selector for jQuery. you need to form a correct selector:

```
   for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
    var theID = aArray[i];
    if (theID.length) {
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().top;
        var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
        if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
            $("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().addClass("active");
        } else {
            $("a[href='" + theID + "']").parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    }
}
```

should instead be:

```
   for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
    var theID = aArray[i];
    var selector = "a[href='" + theID + "']";
    if (theID.length) {
        var divPos = $(selector).offset().top;
        var divHeight = $(selector).height(); // get the height of the div in question
        if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
            $(selector).parent().addClass("active");
        } else {
            $(selector).parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did it fix the issue you posted about? you didn't say anything about highlighting you just listed the javascript console error. if it fixed that issue, please accept the answer and open a new specific issue with the highlighting. thanks.